# creating char device in Linux and open error

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I have HW assignment to create a simple char device.
we are working with RedHad Linux.

after loading the char device with this script:

```
 #!/bin/sh
module="my_module"
device="my_device"
mode="a+w"

# remove stale nodes
rm -f /dev/$device

# invoke insmod with all arguments we got
# and use a pathname, as newer modutils don't look in . by default
/sbin/insmod -f ./$module.o $* || exit 1

major=$(cat /proc/devices | awk "\$2==\"$device\" || \$2==\"$module\" {print \$1}")

mknod /dev/$device c $major 0 || exit 2

# give appropriate group/permissions
chmod $mode  /dev/$device
```

I'm trying to run a script that works with the device, but on OPEN command I receive an error:

> OSError: [Errno 1] Opration not permitted: '/dev/my_device'

I have serched almsot everywhere on the net and couldnot find a resone for the error.

could it be something that came from my open function inside the device?:

```
int my_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    int res = -1;
    if (filp->f_mode & FMODE_READ)
    {
        //
        // handle read opening
        //  
        if(my_major < 0)//in case we need to init the module
        {
            res = init_module();
        }
        if(res != 0)//initiation went wrong
            return res;
        numberOfReadUsers++;
        return my_major;
    }

    if (filp->f_mode & FMODE_WRITE)
    {
        //
        // handle write opening
        //
        if(my_major < 0)//in case we need to init the module
        {
            res = init_module();
        }
        if(res != 0)//initiation went wrong
            return res;
        numberOfWriteUsers++;
        return my_major;
    }

    return 0;
}

int init_module(void)
{
    my_major = register_chrdev(0, MY_DEVICE, &my_fops);

    if (my_major < 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_WARNING "can't get dynamic major\n");
        return my_major;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also have this struct inside my file:

```
struct file_operations my_fops = {
    .open = my_open,
    .release = my_release,
    .read = my_read,
    .write = my_write,
    .ioctl = my_ioctl
};
```

I'm working from super user
any help would be nice :)

Comment: Are the permissions on the device node open enough to permit the python script to access the file?

Comment: can you please explain your question? I'm not sure I understand you

Comment: Are you opening it read/write while the mode only declares write only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the problem.
The open function must return 0...
In my open function I have a case that it might return 1 or -1.
after changing it to return 0 at any point it works.
after searching on the web I found out that this function can return 0 or specific error that are defined in the Linux kernel.